# What Programming Languages a Computer Science Engineer must learn

Tags: programming-languages

During my college I studied C/C++, C#.Net and ASP.Net. Now one my friend suggested me to learn Python & MATLAB also. He wasn't much specific why to learn these languages, He said it would be helpful to get a job with these languages. I've also seen lots of good resume, mostly they have Python (Scripting Language), MATLAB, plus above languages that I've studied. I've to appear for interviews in 3 months, So please guide me what should I do.

Comment: When you get to university, you will see that Computer Science is about learning principles, not specific languages. When you understand algorithms and programming language principles, you will be able to easily learn new languages. What you learn in your program will depend specifically on what your program is like, and what you need to know will depend on where you work after school.

Comment: Haskell. Definitely Haskell. All of it.

Comment: We learned Scheme at the beginning, it's at least a valueable experience to know some functional concepts.

Comment: What is a "Computer Science Engineer"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computer Science and software engineering/development/etc are not about the languages, but about creating solutions to meet a need (solve a problem). Different platforms and languages are tools you will learn to use as you learn and get more experience. All of the languages/platforms you've mentioned in your question are heavily used in software development these days (except maybe FoxPro). You should become knowledgable about all of them (and many others you might come across), and become very proficient in a select few.

You will find that, having mastered one or two languages, becoming productive in others will get easier.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the position/job you apply for.

Some employers may have an urgent need for a person who is productive at day#1. Then they want someone familiar with exactly the language and tools they have in this particular project.

Others may expect you to spend a significant time to learn the company and their special tools. Then it's less important what languages you know, the key is your ability to learn and adapt to their prefered tools.

In general, new languages and tools pops up all the time. Expect to learn add new languages and tools all the time during your career.

Comment: While I agree with what you say here, this has absolutely nothing to do with computer science. Please don't encourage off-topic questions by answering them.